# PDO Insertion error with sub query (SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to Insert a row with a subequery that fetches the data for one of the columns. However, PDO throws an exception at me. What I am basically doing is binding one of the question marks [?] in the arguments list with a sub query.

Here is a little excerpt from the exception:

```
        [1] => Array
            (

                [line] => 147
                [function] => query
                [class] => prepared_statements
                [type] => ->
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => INSERT INTO columns(Name,Column_Type,Is_Permanent) Values(?,?,?)
                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => s
                                [1] => (SELECT Id FROM column_type WHERE Name=\'List_Options\')
                                [2] => 0
                            )

                    )

            )
```

Am I doing something wrong? My best guess is we can't bind a subquery as a parameter?

Thank you for going through this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **can't** and don't have to pass a subquery as a parameter.

To achieve your goal you can just make it a part of your query and only scalar parameters. Your query might look like

```sql
INSERT INTO columns (Name, Is_Permanent, Column_Type) 
SELECT ?,?, (SELECT Id FROM column_type WHERE Name=\'List_Options\')
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9c6571/1)** demo

or if you need to pass `column_type` also as a parameter

```sql
INSERT INTO columns (Name, Is_Permanent, Column_Type) 
SELECT ?,?, (SELECT Id FROM column_type WHERE Name = ?)
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9c6571/2)** demo

Comment: @SPI Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?

Comment: Hi Peterm, thank you for the reply. I figured it out after I posted the question and I selfishly didn't bother returning (*dark look*) I know, I am a monster haha Thanks for the detailed reply :)

Answer (score 3):

You can only bind a single scalar value to a query parameter.  That is, a single string, date, or number.

Parameters cannot be used to substitute for subqueries, SQL expressions, lists of values, SQL keywords, column names, or table names.

Comment: Thanks, Bill! I always love your short yet concise replies!